# Is it possible to change CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE dynamically?

Tags: c++, curl

I'm working on a C++ project that includes statically linked libcurl and I need to increase the CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE to optimize my transfer speeds. I tried redefining the parameter before including "curl/curl.h" only to realize that it didn't do anything. The value remained the same at runtime.

After changing the definition in the curl source and recompiling the entire library it worked. Do I really need to compile the entire library to be able to change this value? If so, why? Trying to find the optimal value will take ages if I can't test and change the parameter at runtime.

Comment: You probably need to compile the curl libs again to be able to change that. Macros can't be changed at runtime.

Comment: But why did the great minds behind curl decide to do it this way instead of just setting a CURLOPT at runtime?

Comment: _"But why did the great minds behind curl decide to do it this"_ Probably because they implemented fixed buffers for efficiency.I can't actually tell.

Comment: see this TODO: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#Modified_buffer_size_approach